# How to show dates in x-axis using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have to draw a line graph but 2 problems arise:

1. My x-axis shows dates with leading zero `01,02,...,31` but only shows them without: `1,2,3,...,31`
2. Repeats `01` at the end, like `01,02,03,...,31,01`

   ```
   var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
   var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
   var formatTime1 = d3.time.format("%d");
   x.domain([xMin,xMax]).nice(s1.length-1)
   y.domain(d3.extent(s1, function(d) { return Math.max(d.value); }));  

   var xMin = d3.min(s1, function(d) { return d.key; });
   var xMax = d3.max(s1, function (d) { return d.key; });
   var xAxis=d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
       .orient("bottom")
       //.ticks(31)
       .ticks(d3.time.days,1)
       .tickFormat(formatTime1)
   var yAxis=d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
       .orient("left")
       .ticks(10);
   ```

The only problem is that on the x-axis dates the last one will print `01`.

How to remove this last `01`?

Comment: Could you provider a fiddle so someone can easily find your issue?

Comment: my data is this type [{"key":[2010,7,1,12],"value":100},{"key":[2010,7,1,24],"value":200}].I draw a graph but x-axis date tickvalues first one repeated last one.How to remove last one

Comment: how to show In the above type of data 12 hour graph and 24 hour multi line chart